# How to print the ACPI table?

Tags: linux-kernel, nvidia, acpi

I'm currently having issues working with NVIDIA drivers on my laptop running linux, and one of the kernel modules I needed was [bbswitch](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/) but it seems as if the project hasn't been updated in several years. The code looks simple enough, so I'm attempting to write my own kernel module.

It seems like I need to understand how ACPI works if I want to do this. My first question is how do I print out the ACPI table? Also, I was wondering if there were any documentation on the linux/acpi.h library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with `bbswitch`, so I don't know how many details you'll need.

While `acpidump` will dump the tables, it's better to dump them in binary format (`acpidump -b`, produces various files) and then use `iasl` to decompile them.

The ACPI standard is quite complex, details can be found [here](https://acpica.org/documentation/) or [here](http://www.uefi.org/acpi/specs). You may have to do quite a bit of reading.

Answer (score 3):

You can use acpidump:

```
$ sudo apt install acpidump
$ man acpidump
```

It creates a lot of output, so perhaps best viewed with `less`:

```
$ acpidump | wc -l
261234
$ acpidump | less
```